# I want to use "border-image ... fill" in GTK+ theme

Tags: themes, gtk3, css

With the following code:

```
border-image: url("assets/sidebar-row.png") 6 23 6 / 6px 23px 6px;
```

No problem, but when I use:

```
border-image: url("assets/sidebar-row.png") 6 23 6 / 6px 23px 6px fill;
```

It fails.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GTK+ specs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html), only the following values are supported:

```
[stretch|repeat|round|space]
```

- The default (stretch) is to resize the slice to fill in the whole allocated area.
- If the value of this property is “repeat”, the image slice will be tiled to fill the area.
- If the value of this property is “round”, the image slice will be tiled to fill the area, and scaled to fit it exactly a whole number of times.
- If the value of this property is “space”, the image slice will be tiled to fill the area, and if it doesn’t fit it exactly a whole number of times, the extra space is distributed as padding around the slices.

So I would use in your example:

```
border-image: url("assets/sidebar-row.png") 6 23 6 / 6px 23px 6px stretch;
```

Comment: @user2610919 Did you try the other options?

Comment: Thanks, but "border-image: url("assets/sidebar-row.png") 6 23 6 / 6px 23px 6px stretch;" will be display as hollow， like this:

https://plus.google.com/+wanfangliu/posts/jW1i9kD1oee

Answer (score 1):

Gtk doesn't yet support `fill`, but it would have to be specified like:

`border-image: url("assets/sidebar-row.png") 6 23 6 fill / 6px 23px 6px;`

because `6 23 6` in your example is the **border-image-slice** part of the **border-image** shorthand property, and `fill` is a **border-image-slice** option.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image